# Go - Parse NULL to time.Time in Struct

Tags: go

I am casting to a struct which has a time.Time type in.

```
t2 := time.Now()
format := "2006-01-02 15:04:05"

theTime, _ := time.Parse(format, t2.Format(format))
```

However, sometimes I don't want to set the time.Time field, how do you define this with the go/mysql db driver?

```
app_history := &models.AppsHistoryInsert{
    AppId:          response.SetAppData[0].Id,
    LiveDate:       &theTime,
}
```

Basically, I want

```
if(x == true) { 
    include time 
}
else {
    don't include time. 
}
```

I tried doing an `if` around the struct declaration itself and leaving the `LiveDate` field out but I got the error of `controllers/apps.go:1068: undefined: app_history`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to define the app_history variable outside the if statement and then assign to it in each of the branches

like so

```
var app_history &models.AppsHistoryInsert{}

if x {
  app_history = &models.AppsHistoryInsert{
    AppId:          response.SetAppData[0].Id,
    LiveDate:       &theTime,
  }
}else {
  app_history = &models.AppsHistoryInsert{
    AppId:          response.SetAppData[0].Id,
  }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, in case there's a bunch more to that init in reality.  Do as is now, but exclude "LiveDate", then just do if x { app_history.LiveDate = &theTime } after you create the initial struct